# How to create a Singleton method which adds a Google Map marker?

Tags: java, android, singleton, google-maps-android-api-2

How to create a method which can add a marker from a SINGLETON. Every time i try, **the map is always null and the marker is always null**.
It doesn't give me NullPointer exception but everything is always 0.

**How to make them not null so the marker can show on the map after i use the call** `Controller.getInstance().adaugaRuta(MapsActivity.this);` **on main activity and use the Map<> objectMap from the method. The problem is here, on the Singleton...i think, because on the main activity i receive the Map<> objectMap with the key i entered but the value is 0 because the marker is null.**

```
public class Controller {
GoogleMap mMap;
private static Controller instance;

private Controller() {
}

public static Controller getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Controller();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Map<String, List<Marker>> adaugaRuta(ShowTheRute theRoute) {

    Map<String, List<Marker>> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
    Marker mae = null;

    IconGenerator iconita = new IconGenerator(MapsActivity.getAppContext());
    iconita.setContentPadding(5, -5, 5, -5);
    iconita.setRotation(-270);
    iconita.setContentRotation(270);
    Bitmap iconbit = iconita.makeIcon("This icon.");

    if (mMap != null) {
  HERE IS THE PROBLEM --->mae = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconbit)).position(new LatLng(46.762035, 23.597659)).anchor(0f, 0.5f));
        mae.isVisible();
    }
    List<Marker> marker1 = new ArrayList<>();
    marker1.add(mae);
    objectMap.put("Marker1", marker1);
    theRoute.getTheRute(objectMap);

    return objectMap;
}
```

The thing is if i remove the `if (mMap != null)` it gives the NullPointerException. I use an interface so i can use the data from Map<> objectMap in MapsActivity which implements the interface. This works, but i get only the key and the value is 0 because the marker is null.

Comment: It looks like your architecture is all wrong.... You should only deal with the data in your singleton, consider changing the return value of `adaugaRuta()` to `Map<String, List<LatLng>>`, and then keep the calls to `mMap.addMarker()` in your Activity.

Comment: Can i ask what are you trying to do? Add Marker on Click or LongClick??

Comment: I have a Auto Complete Text and the map under it. When the user searches for a thing, I just do a simple "if", that thing equals the Map key then it will show the marker. I just don't understand why can't i create a marker.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you didn't define >>>> mMap <<<<<

of course it should always give null pointer Exception !!!

define map someWhere, you can do like this:

```
GoogleMap mMap;
private static Controller instance;

private Controller() {
}

public static Controller getInstance(GoogleMap map) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Controller();
        instance.mMap=map;
    }
    return instance;
}
```

and later in your other function :

```
public Map<String, List<Marker>> adaugaRuta(ShowTheRute theRoute) {

   ...
    if (instance.mMap != null) {
        mae = instance.mMap.addMarker(new  MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconbit)).position(new LatLng(46.762035, 23.597659)).anchor(0f, 0.5f));
        mae.isVisible();
    }
  ..
    return objectMap;
}
```

Comment: Can you please talk with me in private?

Comment: its ok. send me private message. im at your service ;)